# Working with TCO using ts-node - Maximum call stack size exceeded error

Tags: node.js, tail-recursion, ts-node

Does anyone know why this TCO isn't working ?

```js
class RandomClassName {
  strict runForEver(x = 1) {
    console.log(x);
    return this.runForEver(x + 1);
  }
}

RandomClassName.runForEver(); // runs for 1965 calls
```

I'm using `--harmony --use_strict` for `ts-node` like this

```sh
node --stack_size=200 --harmony --use_strict --require ts-node/register ./src/main.ts
```

But it runs into the wall still.

Note: I'm setting `--stack_size` to 200 so it breaks earlier, setting it to 9000 doesn't get a better result then 10221 calls.